# How do I create left and right margins for individual lines of text with vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript

```
const carriage = (e) => {
  let content = document.activeElement
  // alert('hi')
  // let space = content.textContent += '     '
  let space = ' '
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 33; i++) {
    content.textContent += space;  
  }
}
```

I know I'm way off, but how do I create left and right margins for individual lines of text using vanilla javascript? I'm trying to do this using a contenteditable div.

Comment: Usually margins are added using CSS. Notice, that HTML parser ignores most of the leading/trailing white-space, you'd need to add `&nbsp;`s with `innerHTML` to add more spaces to the text.

Comment: In order for white spaces to be preserved, you need to use the `white-space: pre;` CSS property on the element. A much better solution however would be to use [margins](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp) or [padding](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp) depending on what you need.

Comment: What is the actual issue you're resolving by adding the extra white-space?

Comment: why are you not updating CSS margins?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the actual problem, here is a solution assuming you just want to add padding around the content.

The important parts of this solution is this in the CSS

**padding:20px;** Adds 20px padding to the top, right, bottom and left of the div
**box-sizing: border-box;** Allows the border/padding to not affect the width or height of the div

```css
.editor{
  height:400px;
  width:400px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding:20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" class="editor"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the css `white-space: pre` will preserve the spaces in your inner text content for your div.

A loop over each line (split) in the inner text and a recombination (join) at the end will staple it back together with each line having the space padding on the left and right.

```js
const carriage = (e) => {
  let content = document.querySelector('div');
  let space = ' '
  
  let linesOfContent = content.innerText.split('\n');
  content.innerText = linesOfContent.map((line) => {
    let newLine = line;
    for (let i = 0; i < 33; i++) {
     newLine =  space + newLine + space;  
    }
    return newLine
  }).join('\n'); 
}

carriage();
```

```css
div {
  white-space: pre;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">Hello
Hi
Goodbye</div>
```